# gstreamer command to compose (pip) two videos

Tags: video, video-processing, gstreamer, video-editing

What command should I execute in gstreamer in order to compose two 320x240 videos into a single 640x240 side-by-side video?

let's say I have video1.avi and video2.avi

Comment: It's possible and I've done it, but the last time I tried the resulting framerate was very wrong and slow. Maybe someone can elucidate. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, any other approach, anything else I can use in the sever side for composing/editing the videos?

Answer (score 5):

videomixer plugin to the rescue:

```
gst-launch -v \
filesrc location=video1.avi ! avidemux name=demux1 \
filesrc location=video2.avi ! avidemux name=demux2 \
videomixer name=mix \
        sink_0::xpos=0   sink_0::ypos=0 sink_0::alpha=0 \
        sink_1::xpos=0   sink_1::ypos=0 \
        sink_2::xpos=320 sink_2::ypos=0 \
    ! xvimagesink \
videotestsrc pattern="black" \
    ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=240 \
    ! mix.sink_0 \
demux1.video_00 \
    ! queue ! decodebin ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240 \
    ! mix.sink_1 \
demux2.video_00 \
    ! queue ! decodebin ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240 \
    ! mix.sink_2 \
```

Comment: This is a good answer. If using `uridecodebin` instead of `filesrc` how to reference the files? Do I still have to set a variable name, if so how?

Comment: Yes, I think it's possible to do the work without `name`: just remove lines with `filesrc ...` and replace `demuxX.video00 ! queue ! decodebin` with `urldecodebin`.